# MySQL: Use WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause in python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to get the CaseID from my table of the last ban. The table is like that:

```
Field          Type         Null   Key      Default     Extra
CaseID         int(11)      NO     PRIMARY  NULL        AUTO INCREMENT
CaseType       varchar(10)  YES    NULL 
UserID         varchar(30)  YES    NULL 
ModeratorID    varchar(30)  YES    NULL 
Reason         varchar(500) YES    NULL 
ExpirationDate datetime     YES    NULL
```

What I already have:

```
case_id = "SELECT CaseID FROM RLH_Cases_v2 WHERE CaseType = Ban ORDER BY CaseType DESC LIMIT 1"
modlog_db.mycursor.execute(case_id)
```

So, I want to get the case id of the last ban. I tried to do that by ordering by CaseType. But there are multiple CaseTypes. Like "Warn", "Kick" and "Ban". So I wrote `WHERE CaseType = Ban`.
But I got that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Team Stuff (TS, DC, MC)\RLH\Programming\OnMessage.py Rewrite\Commands\Unban.py", line 23, in unban
    modlog_db.mycursor.execute(case_id)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 269, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 510, in cmd_query
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Ban' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: For string literals use single quotes: `WHERE CaseType = 'Ban'`

Comment: Ah worked now, thanks

Comment: Also what defines the last ban? Last by ExpirationDate or CaseId. In any case ORDER BY <that column>.